# Pyminifier (obfuscation) does not appear to change anything other than in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation, pyinstaller, decompiling

I am attempting to obfuscate my python code with `pyminifier`.  Generally I would use SAAS, however it is not within the budget of this small project nor is it feasible to host this as a server application.  I have tried the following code:

```
pyminifier --nonlatin --replacement-length=50 C:/hi.py
```

Though when I edit the file it does not appear to be any different. The same can be said when I open with `Uncompile6`. Am I missing something?  It changes in command line or appears to.  If I distributed this through pyinstaller, the code appears to change in cmd but does not seem any different.

Comment: pyminifier doesn't change the source file, it sends its output to the terminal. You need to capture that output to a file yourself, eg by redirection. Why do you want to use `--replacement-length=50`? Surely shorter names would make the code more obfuscated.

Comment: @PM2Ring I see.  That would explain why nothing has changed.  There does does not seem to be much documentation on this, would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: I don't use Windows, but I'm pretty sure that standard redirection syntax works in your command prompt, eg `pyminifier -O --nonlatin --replacement-length=5 C:/hi.py >C:/newhi.py`

Comment: @PM2Ring My exact output is # Created by pyminifier`.  Does not seem to obfuscate correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In default, `pyminifier` only make the file smaller(deleting unnecessary white spaces, comments....).
You probably want to run:

```
pyminifier -O --nonlatin --replacement-length=50 C:/hi.py
```

Comment: Apparently this does not change source, but there is an additional step of redirecting it.  I can't find anything on that though. Perhaps converting to a pyz - like pyminifier --pyz=C:/hi1.pyz C:/hi1.py.  It's produces an error though I have a large library of imports...

Comment: To be honest, this library is so out of date it's amazing it works at all xD

Comment: ﱟ=True
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier